# jQuery toggle multiple divs within other divs independently

Tags: jquery

I've checked through the related questions but I haven't found the right combination of things to make this work.

I'm trying to hide / show a div within a another div. There are 20 of such wrapper divs per page.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="date"></div>
    <div class="subject"></div>
    <div class="who"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to show the class="body" div which is set to display:none; in css.

I've tried using the jQuery toggle(), toggleClass() functions with no success.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
$('.wrapper').click(function () {
    $('.body').toggle();
});
```

I know it's a very tiny piece of code, sadly I've just started to learn jQuery and don't know how to proceed from this.

Comment: this works, see my answer, I'm guessing something else is up. Make sure you're wrapping your `click` event in `$(function(){ /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting it in the onready function. Like so:

```
$(function () {
  $('.wrapper').click(function () {
    $('.body').toggle();
  });
});
```

Putting it in this function ensures it'll run after the document has completely loaded... otherwise it'll try to attach the click handler to an element that hasn't loaded yet (and therefore, doesn't exist).

Comment: The problem with this code is that it will toggle ALL of the body divs, not just the body div in the clicked wrapper.

Comment: Oh, I assumed only one would be showing at a time. Don't know why I assumed that. You want `$(this).find('.body').toggle();` instead of `$('.body').toggle();`.

Comment: @Dutchie432 yes, you did :) Sorry for hijacking. +1 on your answer.

Comment: Maclnnes, your solution works. I guess I didn't see any result because it wasn't in a function and the $(this).find('.body').toggle(); fixed the opening of all elements instead of only one.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/XGsVE/3/). This code will toggle the BODY div of the clicked WRAPPER. Leaving out the `$(this)` causes ALL of the BODY divs to toggle, despite the wrapper they are in.

```
$('.wrapper').click(function () {
    $(this).find('div.body').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Works as you said, I just had to put it into a function like Nathan suggested.

Comment: Then I suggest using `$(document).ready(function(){...})` as opposed to just `function(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to select what you want to toggle off of another class if you want to be able to hide it again.  Toggling the `body` class will remove it from the `div` sow when you click the `wrapper` again, it will not be selectable.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    W
    <div class="date">d</div>
    <div class="subject">s</div>
    <div class="who">w</div>
    <div class="body isbody">b</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('.wrapper').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.isbody').toggleClass('body');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuBNd/

Comment: how can you click something that isn't visible?

Comment: well, this will definitely work 1 time since you'll be removing the `.body` class on the first click

Comment: the asker wanted to toggle the class.